# consuming SOAP web service in non-boot spring application

Tags: soap, soap-client, spring-ws

I have a java application which is not spring boot. Can I write a client for consuming SOAP based web services? All the examples online use org.springframework.ws which is part of spring-boot. Also I don't want to use either Axis2 or CXF

Comment: You mean, like with [JAX-WS](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html)?

Comment: I meant to use spring-ws. There isn't proper documentation if I can use spring-ws only with spring boot applications.

Comment: So, your actual question seems to be "Can I use Spring-WS without Spring Boot?" Then, my question is, what makes you think you can't?

Comment: I'm not able to add org.springframework.ws to my project (pom.xml) if my parent is not spring-boot. I'm not able to find a way to get around it

Comment: I figured out my self. The following dependency worked:         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>